# Extract the .position() of all elements of type to their child <span> elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, parent

Hello i have the following configuration:

HTML

```
<div id="sortable">
  <div class="hi" id="100">One hundred<span></span></div>
  <div class="hi" id="200">Two hundred<span></span></div>
  <div class="hi" id="300">Three hundred<span></span></div>
  <div class="hi" id="400">Four hundred<span></span></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#sortable > *.hi').click(function () {
  $('span', '#sortable > *.hi').text($(this).position().top);
});
```

I want whenever I click one of the sub-divs (.hi) to change the text to each span with the location of its parent. 
Here's a jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/v7w5E/

EDIT:

As Rajaprabhu suggected below i can use .each()

here is an updated jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/v7w5E/3/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what exactly isn't working, the Fiddle seem to be working just fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want whenever I click one of the sub-divs (.hi) to change the text to each span with the location*

Try to use `.each()` at this context,

```
   var elements = $('#sortable > .hi');
   elements.click(function() {   
      elements.each(function(){
          $('span',this).text($(this).position().top);
      });
   });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v7w5E/3/)

Comment: @user2632961 Glad to help..! And by the way if you think that this answer has satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark present with this answer to show your acceptance.. and this is not a compulsion... :)

Comment: hehe i tried exacly after i saw it works :) i have to wait 10-20 seconds more